What do the makers of Project 2025 consider "pornography"?
The foreword of Project 2025, "The Conservative Promise", Chapter 1, contains a text about restoring and "protecting" the family, including this passage:

Pornography, manifested today in the omnipresent propagation of
transgender ideology and sexualization of children, for instance, is
not a political Gordian knot inextricably binding up disparate claims
about free speech, property rights, sexual liberation, and child
welfare. It has no claim to First Amendment protection. Its purveyors
are child predators and misogynistic exploiters of women. Their
product is as addictive as any illicit drug and as psychologically
destructive as any crime. Pornography should be outlawed. The people
who produce and distribute it should be imprisoned. Educators and
public librarians who purvey it should be classed as registered sex
offenders. And telecommunications and technology firms that facilitate
its spread should be shuttered.

While a total ban and criminalization of porn is already a very harsh and socially authoritarian proposal, the highlighted sentences sound weird and potentially scary. Simply, because "transgender ideology" isn't usually transported through porn, and children usually don't see porn as part of whatever "sexualization". Pornography is also not usually provided by educational facilities and libraries.
When I hear "pornography", I usually think of sexually explicit descriptions and depictions, mainly for the purpose of sexual arousal. Like the usual "adult" sites on the web.
So what do they mean? Any education about forms of sexuality they don't like? Any education on sexual topics?
Source: project2025.org , PDF download of full "Mandate for Leadership".

In general, there's no precisely-defined meaning of pornography. In one of the Supreme Court's most famous rulings, in the case Jacobellis v. Ohio, Justice Potter Stewart wrote:

I shall not today attempt further to define the kinds of material I understand to be embraced within that shorthand description ["hard-core pornography"], and perhaps I could never succeed in intelligibly doing so. But I know it when I see it, ...

Judging from the text you quoted, the group behind Project 2025 "knows it when they see it", and they apparently consider any material that normalizes "transgender ideology" to be pornography, and thus not protected by the 1st Amendment. It doesn't have to be "sexually explicit" like adult movies -- transgenderism is deviant to them, and is inherently obscene.
This is consistent with a conservative movement around the country over the past few years to get nearly all LGBTQ+-related material banned from school libraries (and even public libraries in some cases).

More an amendment than a real answer: I found this article by The New Republic, which claims that they use "pornography" as a synonym for everything sexual, which they don't like, not just the average adult content. They also look at Russia and Hungary, where anti-sexual and particularly anti-LGBTQ action and criminal persecution has become part of general, authoritarian rule.
https://newrepublic.com/article/183636/project-2025-war-porn-trans-drag

In Hungary, registered partnership of LGBT people is legal. There is no persecution of LGBT people.

@AdamGyenge There is clearly a strong trend to try to curb those rights since Orbán came to power, and at the very least some strong rethoric https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viktor_Orb%C3%A1n#Anti-LGBT_policies

Context
Due to the recent media storm about the subject, I feel that this context is important before tackling it.
This project was produced by the Herritage foundation, and has no direct ties to the republican nomenee. However, they do have a lot of influence among religious republicans, and this project could guide their actions.
Trump, while religious himself, has historically been at odds with the religious caucus. His first vice president pick was an attempt to appease them. There are also known conflicts between them, for example the rejection of an abortion ban from Trump.
Banning pornography is something that has been considered by the most religious for decades, however, it is seen as political suicide, even if they see it as a worthy cause. Even the most religious see a ban on pornography as an extreme act, and tends to, at most, demmand that pornography websites have safety measures to prevent minors from accessing.
This document is not focused on practical political strategy and it is more like an idealized vision of what they, the Herritage foundation, would do if they were in power.
Definition of pornography
The definition is intentionally left vague, commonly described as "I know it when I see it" since they claim that pornography is extremely unpredictable, and hard to categorize. What diferentiates erotic from non erotic material can be something very subtle.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it
Transgenderism is not part of the definition of pornography in their view, but a potential vector of normalization:

children suffer the toxic normalization of transgenderism with drag queens and pornography invading their school libraries.

So when they mention educators and librarians being registered as sex offenders, this is unrelated to transgenderism. They are referring to the act of providing erotic material to minors.
While this doesn't necessarily includes lgbt advocacy or education about it, it does include drag queens, for example, which they claim is analogous to a stripper or cabaret performer, which are erotic in nature.
For example this senate bill which bans the performance of “sexually oriented” shows in front of minors.
https://capitol.texas.gov/BillLookup/History.aspx?LegSess=88R&Bill=SB12
While there is no precise definition of what is pornographic, some past actions from religious republicans could be used to provide a reference to at least what they see as inapropriate for children.
https://www.pnj.com/story/news/education/2023/09/22/florida-leads-nation-in-book-bans-full-list-of-banned-books/70934406007/
